# How image is reduced to 7x7 by TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I'm reading the tutorial [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html). At the start of the section [Densely Connected Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#densely-connected-layer), it says that "[...] the image size has been reduced to 7x7".

I can't seem to find out how they get to this 7x7 matrix. To my understanding, we start at 28x28 and have two layers of a 5x5 convolution kernels. 28 divided by 4 is 7, but not divided by 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5x5 is the "window" size for the convolution layer.  It does not reduce the image size: TensorFlow and Caffe, among others, automatically supply a border pad.  Torch, to name one, requires you to add that border (2 locations in each direction, in this case).

Each kernel (filter) considers a 5x5 subset of the entire image.  For instance, to compute the value for position [7, 12] in the image, the convolution process considers the "window" [5:9, 10:14].  It multiplies each of these 25 values by its corresponding weight and sums those products.  This sum becomes the value in the next layer for the center square [7,12].

This process repeats for every position in the image, and for each kernel in the layer.

As @Aenimated1 already mentioned, the size reduction comes from two poolings of 2x each.  This operation divides the image into 2x2 windows, passing along the maximum value (or other representation, should the user specify) of each 2x2 square.  This reduces the 28x28 image to 14x14; the second pooling reduces it to 7x7.

Answer (score 2):

The reduction in the "image size" is the result of the pooling layers added after each convolutional layer.  Each 2x2 pooling decreases the width and height by a factor of 2, thus yielding a 7x7 matrix after both pooling ops.